# what is the plan for Threadgroup in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I was taking a look at the threading library for python3 and was wondering what the group parameter was supposed to do. i know its just a placeholder. but what would it do where it implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it relates to the Java ThreadGroup class concept, as the python multithreading module design was inspired by the Java thread-related classes.  The Java ThreadGroup class basically represents a set of threads, allowing a thread to access information about its own thread group, but not any other thread groups.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html